# Is there a menu like interactive commit for SVN like Git has with --interactive?

Tags: linux, git, svn, shell, version-control

Most probably you know in git you can get a very good commit experience by using

```
git commmit --interactive
```

which will show up a menu, where you can add/update/patch/revert things, and you select files by their range, eg: 1-5,10-12,100-1135

```
$ git commit --interactive
           staged     unstaged path


*** Commands ***
  1: [s]tatus     2: [u]pdate     3: [r]evert     4: [a]dd untracked
  5: [p]atch      6: [d]iff       7: [q]uit       8: [h]elp
What now>
```

I am looking to get the same functionality in SVN like a **shell command**.
Do you know what is the SVN command?

Comment: Hmm, if you are using SVN, you could use git-svn, since it has "read/write" support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bad news is that there is no such thing as interactive command line prompt for svn. Good news is that you can write your own and be the first to come up with such a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have that kind of feature in the CLI (Command Line Interface, ie "with a shell command") of SVN.

Of course, you have some of it in a GUI like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html) (Windows) or [RabbitVCS (Linux)](http://rabbitvcs.org/), but this is a *graphical* solution, not a command-line one (so again, *not* a shell Command).

Graphically, the enhanced commit looks like:

[image: graphical commit]

Comment: This is not an answer for my question, this is for Windows perhaps.

Comment: @Pentium10: my point is that you will find the features you mention in a GUI (like this Windows one, but there are others for other Os: RabbitVCS for instance is the TortoiseSVN for Linux: http://rabbitvcs.org/). Not in a CLI.

Comment: @Pentium10: I have edited my answer to emphasized the "no shell command available" (as far as I know) part.

Answer (score 0):

in spirit of altem's answer, i just did:

```
# collect a list modified files
svn st > temp.sh
# use your favourite editor (although it is vim, right?) 
# to edit list into suitable svn command or commands
vim temp.sh
# execute
. ~/temp.sh
```

and made a command to commit a selection of files

gad that is ugly

but easier than doing multiple `svn ci` commits and `svn st`

Answer (score 0):

Opinion: I find `svn` very badly designed for the command line and scripting in general...

But I often use `find` and its `-ok` expression when I want to prompt user:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec svn info {} \; -a -ok svn delete {} \;
```

Note that in the case you don’t want `svn info` output, you have to invoke a subshell as follows (otherwise `-ok` will not output at all):

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec sh -c 'svn info "{}" 2>/dev/null' \; -a -ok svn delete {} \;
```